# sending sms to url in android

Tags: android, url, sms

I am developing an Android based application in which I have to send SMS to a URL.

Comment: In order to increase the chances of getting feedback, you should provide as much info as possible... This seems a little vague.

Comment: trgaglia,,I have to send sms to url..How can i do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMS is a mobile network based task. And a URL is related to the Internet. 
So you can't literally 'send an SMS' to a URL. 
However, you can send some data to a URL using two methods - GET and POST. 
For Example Look at Google's URL:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=search+terms&safe=active&qscrl=1
```

Here we are sending three parameters to the Google.com server:
1. q (=search terms)
2. safe (=active)
3. qscrl (=1)

The + in the URL is a whitespace.

Here's a link that show's the difference b/n GET and POST methods:
http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html

Answer (score 1):

You can set a gateway that will receive the SMS message and connect to the desired URL, before sending back an answer if needed.

No special programming is needed on the Android side, just call the URL.

Answer (score 1):

There are some paid APPs that do that.

one of them is this:

[Forward SMS to URL](https://www.forward-sms-to-rest-api.com/forward_sms_to_rest_api.php)